# SQL Server 2008 - TSQL Read CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv, import

I am working on a project that basically entails on importing a CSV file into a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. The CSV file is generated from an Excel file that is populated by a "manager" with PR hours for his employees. This also includes some additional information such as which job and phase the employees were working on and also includes the number of hours for an equipment (if used).

Once you generate a CSV file for that, it's not exactly the usual straighforward "column" based CSV file. It's more like a "row" based CSV file with each row being kind of unique. Due to this caveat involved, I cannot do a straight dump (using BULK insert or OPENROWSET) to SQL, which would essential create a (temp) table with the appropriate column filled data.

I am looking to use the fields within the CSV file based on the "location" of that field in the row.

So, basically the positions of the data will remain the same, since every CSV is based on a TEMPLATE file - so all I have to do is navigate through the CSV file using SQL code to find the right field based on it's position in the ROW. I hope that gives you guys a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve here. *Sorry for the long wall of text.*

I researched a bit and here's what I have come up with so far:

Reads CSV files into a temp table through a custom SQL function (**Reading lines from a file**)
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

This one is interesting. Dumps the whole file as a BLOB and then you can sift through the data. 
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1643/using-openrowset-to-read-large-files-into-sql-server/

Finally, this one essential splits out the rows and creates separates records per row. Interesting..
http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/17408/how-to-read-a-text-file.html

If anyone has any suggestions or steps that I could follow to get through this, I would greatly appreciate it.

To the Mods: If I have posted something (especially the links) that shouldn't be here, please feel free to remove it. I apologize if I did.

Thanks much.. Hope to hear some positive responses! :)

Warm Regards,
Pranav

Comment: I suppose loading directly from Excel is out of the question?

Comment: would an UNPIVIOT/PIVOT function help at all? ie dump the file as is then use a stored proc to arrange the data how you want it?

Comment: @tkendrick20 I can't use Excel directly since it's not exactly an excel file. It doesn't have definite "columns". The CSV file that's generated from that Excel file is basically a file with "rows" of data that don't have any associated FIXED columns.

Comment: @DevN00B I am not sure of that method. I have never used it before, could you please give me an example? Thanks! :)

Comment: @SillyCoda. If you google pivot and unpivot it will give you examples. by the sounds of it you are going to have to dump the data into a database then run a query against it to separate the strings into what you want to be columns then pivot that to make sense

Comment: Perhaps think more along the lines of GUI front end like a VB app. It would be very easy to create a program that reads your csv and has conditions coded to know where to place the content in the SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not too large, another option is to post-process the file in Excel using a VBA macro. Of course, you'd need to come up to speed using the Excel object model and VBA, but the recording function makes it fairly simple. One advantage of the VBA approach is that it seems you really do want to do row by row processing, and VBA is better for that, whereas SQL is better for set-based operations.